# Why keyspace metadata is null only when connecting to datastax enterprise 6.8 with cassandra-driver?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-driver, dse

We have a requirement to support **Datastax Enterprise 6.8**.Installed DSE6.8 on aws ec2 linux by referring https://docs.datastax.com/en/install/6.8/install/dseBasicInstall.html.
Our code does support Apache cassandra,drivers we use are **cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0**.We use following code for the connection

```
Cluster.Builder builder = Cluster.builder();
String strMultipleNodes = connectionInfo.getNodes();    
        builder.addContactPointsWithPorts(getMultipleNodes(strMultipleNodes));
        Session session = builder.build().connect(connectionInfo.getKeySpace());
```

In the session,keyspace metadata is present when connecting to Apache cassandra,but when we connect to Datastax Enterprise 6.8,**keyspace metadata is null**.We are trying to get table metadata from the session value,but as keyspace metadata is null,not able to retreive table info.

```
poolObject.getSession().getCluster().getMetadata().getKeyspace(poolObject.getSession().getLoggedKeyspace()).getTable(activityConfig.getTableName());
```

Can anyone please let me know why this happens?